# How to respond to code-revision assistance? Answer, or Comment

Tags: support, code

I like stackoverflow because there are so many talented people helping each other out. I would like to know what is the best way to respond to a suggestion to my question, i.e., sharing the code changes from the suggestions. Do I post it as an "answer"? or do i post it as a comment? how would formatting be for `Code` in a comment?

Answer (score 3):

Code doesn't format well in comments.

If the new code answers the question directly, post it as an answer, with explanatory text included.  But I would only do this once.  Don't repeatedly post answers showing revisions to the code.

If the code merely clarifies an existing answer, or consolidates suggestions by several answer posters, I would put the new code at the bottom of the question, separated by a line, like this:

---

Here is my final code:

```
my foo(is barred)
{
    // I do things here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it as an update to your question. If you mark that section of your question as **Update** and then put the code changes below it, there should be a clear delineation between your original question and the updates you received from people. This should also format much better than attempting to put code in a comment.

Just my opinion, of course...